# Как в PostgreSQL заблокировать возможность читать и записывать данные если чтение или запись уже идёт

Tags: python, postgresql, telebot, psycopg2

Есть 2 бота и одна БД. Один бот основной, второй дополнение. Возникла проблема, если в основном боте пользователь совершает действие с данными в таблице X и параллельно совершит действие в дополнительном боте с данными в таблице X, то данные могут не сохраниться.
Пример. Имеем: `Y=100, B=0`. Основной бот отнимает от переменной `Y - 100`, дополнительный бот отнимает от переменной `Y - 100` и прибавляет к переменной `B + 100` (всё это происходит в один момент). Получаем что Y так и осталась 100, а B получила значение 100. Результат: `Y=100, B=100` хотя должно быть `Y=0, B=100`.

Рассматривал такое решение. При получении данных из таблицы ставить блокировку
`get_x = "SELECT x FROM table WHERE id=%s FOR SHARE"`
это вроде даже помогло, но надеюсь есть решение проще, т.к. этот вариант требует внести огромное кол-во правок в коде.

Вторым решением было присвоить уровень блокировки всем таблицам.

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

но увы это совсем не помогло.

Как по умолчанию в таблице блокировать строку на чтение и запись, когда эта строка занята чтением или записью?

Comment: Решение гораздо сложней чем вы себе представляете :) скажу сразу - из коробки решения нет :) вы можете завести отдельное поле(в котором будете хранить информацию о "блокировке") и следить за его содержимым самостоятельно, решение на блокировках - нерабочее(предупреждаю просто заранее, пока ваша БД не задохнулась от DEADLOCK`ов)

Comment: Покажите как точно (какими операциями) происходит обновление данных в таблице. Y ни как не может остаться 0, если два процесса вычитают 100 из 100. Если первый бот будет явно делать `update table set Y=Y-100 WHERE id=%s` а второй процесс будет выполнять при этом `update table set Y=Y-100, B=B+100 WHERE id=%s`. то вы гарантированно получите Y=-100 (потому что 100 вычитали 2 раза) B=100

Comment: Пример непонятен. Не ясно почему `Y=0, B=100` это ожидаемое поведение, если два бота отнимают по 100 от Y, объясните. Так же не ясно как так в результате получается `Y=100`.

Comment: @Mike сначала через SELECT оба бота получают данные из таблицы, представим что это происходит в одно время. Данные получены и записаны в локальную переменную. В этой перемнной происходит вычитание и затем через UPDATE записываем получившийся результат обратно в бд.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA возможно не совсем верный пример привёл. Y=100. Первый бот: Y-1. Второй бот Y-100 и B+100. И это происходит в одно время. Оба бота получили значение из бд Y=100, боты провели вычитание и первый бот позже записал результат, т.е. Y-1=99. Выходит что какой-то из ботов должен был столкнуться с тем что Y=99 или 0. И так выходит что мы вычли больше чем можно было, да ещё и записали то что вычли в другую перемнную. Так в игре люди могут дюпать ресурсы и валюту

Comment: Если у вас транзакции уже явно размечены, то решением будет уровень изоляции serializable и повтор транзакции, когда случается ошибка cannot serialize. Почитайте про этот уровень изоляции, он делает так, что транзакции выполняются как-бы последовательно, а если постгрес видит конфликт, то возвращает ошибку. Плюс такой, что логику приложения можно не менять, в приложении как-будто других транзакций нет (за исключением того, что может произойти этот конфликт и нужно транзакцию перезапустить, но это делается централизовано). Минус в том, что при частых конфликтах лучше явная блокировка.

Comment: Транзакции и так в любом решении придется явно размечать. А для явной блокировки `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE/FOR SHARE` придется еще и все запросы менять.

Comment: @ih8sn0w Ну тогда вам от for share никуда не уйти, это наиболее правильное решение. (либо переделать запросы более кардинально, так, как показал я в примерах, в начале). Остался вопрос почему добавление `for share` требует внесения огромного количества правок. У вас видимо что то не так с кодом, раз обновление одной и той же таблицы есть во многих местах. Надо стараться структурировать код так, что бы однотипные действия вроде обновления конкретной таблицы были по возможности только в одном месте (например в одной функции и эта функция бы вызывалась возможно из обоих ботов)

Comment: Для примера с Y и B `for share` будет мало, ведь две транзакции все равно смогут прочитать одновременно и потом по очереди записать каждая свое. for share нужно использовать только для данных, которые транзакция только читает, а для тех которые меняет нужен for update. Почему добавление сейчас помогло? Вероятно просто поменялось немного время выполнения и проблема конкурентного изменения не случается, но гонки все еще есть и могут проявиться в любой момент.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA уровень изоляции Serializable или Repeatable read действительно подходит в данной ситуации, не знаю как это отразится на весь остальной функционал, но при проверке именно данной ситуации получается ошибка could not serialize access due to concurrent update. Осталось придумать как перезапускать попытку при ошибке при этом не меняя код половины бота :)

Comment: @Mike большое кол-во правок потому что код бестолково написан, писал бота просто по фану, постепенно исправляю ошибки прошлого, но объём работы слишком велик как для проекта который делаю просто на досуге) Зато какой опыт)